# Angular.js directive not responding on changes on attributes

Tags: angularjs

I have searched and searched, tried and tried but nothing seems to work: I have an element directive with some attributes e.g width="width" and I'm changing this attributes in the controller on resize event on window, I have set the binding as "=" but if I watch for 'width' it works once but then it doesn't, I have tried the watch with true, tried observe on attrs, tried changing bindings, nothing works, any ideas?

Maybe I should call digest or apply?

```
function Ctrl1($scope, $window) {
$scope.width = $window.innerWidth;
$scope.height = $window.innerHeight;

angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
    $scope.width = $window.innerWidth;
    $scope.height = $window.innerHeight;
    console.log($scope.width, $scope.height);
});
$scope.name = 'angular';
$scope.counter = 0;

$scope.myClick = function() {
    $scope.height++;
    $scope.width++;
}
}

angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myElement', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        'width': '=',
        'width': '='
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="myOtherClick()">From Directive</button>',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        scope.myOtherClick = function() {
            scope.width++;
            scope.height++;
        }
    }
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2y1brpzf/

Comment: @JBNizet: added a fiddle

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work in Chrome. One thing to note is that you have two 'width' attributes on scope in the directive.

Comment: @camden_kid it wasnt working dynamically, check my new fiddle in the answer, $scope.$digest() is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two solutions:

**1.** In your directive, set:

```
    scope: {
      width: '@',
    },
```

and then do

```
attrs.$observe('width', function(passedId) {
```

**2.** 
Use your attribute as a function, in directive:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        return element.attr('width');//value to be watched;
      }, function watchCallback(newVal, oldVal) {
(..) 
}
```

These two work fine in angular 1.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it adding $scope.$digest(); after updating width and height in controller:

```
$scope.$digest();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2y1brpzf/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cqpg5gvv/3/ without digest seems to work dynamically (as per my comment above)

Comment: @camden_kid when You resize the window you get dynamically logs just or also the html is dynamic? Coz for me it doesnt work without :/

Comment: Yes, it dynamically logs when the window is resized. :-) I'm using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.99 and on Firefox too.

Comment: Logs, ok thats normal but it should dynamically change the html, if You try mine and resize the window you will see it changes the html too :)

Comment: Ah, understood. Glad you found a solution. :-)